# Can you tweak the feedback for alt-tab in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, colors

I have recently changed from 18.04 to 20.04, and the popup when you press Alt-Tab has changed. Mostly I approve, but I find the highlight around the selected item almost invisible against the background — two nearby shades of grey. Is there any way to change these colors?

Comment: it is possible if you are willing to edit the gnome-shell css files..

Comment: Agree. I also find them hard to distinguish. Would really appreciate an answer!

Comment: Same issue with 22.04. I would also be grateful for a solution.